# Views sort criteria setup by number of fields

Tags: views

I am using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with exposed so visitors can search on items that are published by other users.

Content type that views is showing has 50 fields (+ 3 taxonomy fields with around 200 terms). 
Only 7 fields are mandatory. Rest are there to better describe the item. Rarely someone uses all fields but most are using half.

Reward for using as many fields+terms as possible per content would result in higher position in view sort criteria.

**Example:** Users A and B have 2 nodes each.

A1 = 7 fields used

A2 = 12 fields used

B1 = 8 fields used

B2 = 10 fields used

Views results: A1, B1, B10, A12

Is there a way to do this with views ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this. (It is not the exact code, but it will help you.)

```
function findNodesByUser($userID) {
$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->propertyCondition('type', $type) //Where $type is the type of node
  ->propertyCondition('uid', $userID)
  ->execute();
}

function createArray() {
    customArray = array();
    $users = entity_load('user');

    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $user_nodes = findNodesByUser($user);
        foreach($user_nodes as $user_node) {
            customArray[$user . $user_node] = count(field_get_items('node', $entity, $field_name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not good at coding so i dont know where to use this. Ill try to explain question better. Node that has more inputs (used fields) should get higher on views sort criteria. If user A has used 15 fields, and user B 70 fields, first result should be of user B.

Comment: @BigBrother2010 Please edit your question, use full sentences and the exact names Drupal also uses to describe their structure. The code in this answer is pseudocode for looping trough all the nodes a user has created for all users. There you can probably find all fields that are used for that node. It's just a direction in the right way